# VSCode Remote SSH: Run Python File in New Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

I am using the Remote SSH extension for VSCode. Whenever I try to run a Python file in the Python terminal using the `Run Python File in Terminal` command, while the terminal is already executing another python program, VSCode tries to execute the new program in the **same** Python terminal, instead of opening a new terminal. Is there a way to execute each python program in a new terminal so that multiple programs can run simultaneously?

**Edit**: Tried to open a new Python terminal explicitly, but still, the `Run Python File in Terminal` is always routed to the first terminal. If I run the Python program explicitly in the new terminal by typing `python my_prog.py` it works, but I am looking for an interactive way.

Comment: Tried to set in `launch.json` `"console": "externalTerminal"` as you suggested, but actually, it had no effect.

Comment: Did you click _F5_ to debug the code after setting "launch.json"?

Comment: I don't want to run in debug mode since this is much slower. Also this doesn't work too as I get `can't find terminal application 'xterm'` on F5

Comment: -At present, in VS Code, in addition to manually inputting execution commands, debugging code can be implemented in multiple terminals to run the code. If F5 does not work, please try to click the "[Start Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_basic-debugging)" button of VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

In VS Code, the command "Run Python File in Terminal" is executed by default in a "default" "Terminal", which avoids the impact of runtime confusion and reduces the time to find python and file paths at runtime.

If synchronization is required, VS Code currently does not support running two or more terminals simultaneously. You can refer to this link:
[Can VSCode automatically run python scripts in two or more terminals at the same time?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094)

If you don’t require synchronization, only need to be in a new independent terminal every time the code is executed, you can set it in "launch.json": `"console": "externalTerminal",`

Then click `Ctrl+F5` to run the code or click `F5` to debug the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion link [Can VSCode automatically run python scripts in two or more terminals at the same time?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094) provided by @jill-cheng, since 9th May 2023 it is possible. The "Run Python in Dedicated Terminal" option has been added at least in the pre-released version.

[Image showing the newly added option "Run Python in Dedicated Terminal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8zGF.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34784278)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).